# Getting Spring Boot Security login to work properly for Firefox

Tags: java, spring, firefox, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a strange situation with my Spring Boot app 's login functionality with Firefox.

My HttpSecurity in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter has configured the login like this :

```
.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .permitAll()
```

I have a login.html page and a GetMapping set up to load that load that page up at the /login endpoint :

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String get(Model model) {
    return "login";
}
```

There is no PostMapping to handle the POST-ing

So, the logging in flow works perfectly fine for Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox.

When I try to log in on FireFox, it will always say HTTP Post 405 Method not allowed.

Now, if I add this to the HttpSecurity to disable CSRF

```
 .and().csrf().disable();
```

then Firefox will not return 405, but will successfully redirect to "/" as configured, but is not properly logging in the user, i.e. : SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated() is false.

What else did I miss?

Thanks

Comment: Which spring version you used?

Comment: As a general note, it's usually better not to repeat default configuration--essentially everything in your config is already the default, and specifying it makes it more difficult to see what actual settings you change.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna My Spring version should be 4

Comment: Yea @chrylis , I am trying to experiment to figure out why it is not working in Firefox

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to open up the Network tab and examine the requests being made. It might also help if you post the form section of your login page template.

Comment: Debug your html code(Open page -> Right Click -> View Page source) in the mozilla browser and see if the csrf tokens are properly generated in the tags.